# How to realize a timer with qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a c++ qt program. I tried to realize a countdown timer with `lcdnumber` and, in the slots function, I used a `qtime` object to track the current time,and three `int h,m,s` to mark the countdown time.

I thought that `s-time.second` should be the second part of the time it should display, and it turned out to be always showing 0.

If I let it display `time.second` minus a static number like 3(`time.second-3`),then it'll work.

Does the `h,m,s` change all the time?
What should I do?

```
 QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
int s=time.second();
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showTime(int)));
    timer->start(10);

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::showTime(){


        QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
        int b=(s-time.second()+60)%60;

        auto o=QTime(h,m,b,0);
        QString timestr = o.toString("hh:mm:ss"); 

        ui->lcdNumber->display(timestr);
}
···
```

Comment: `timer->start(0);` is a strange thing to call, since the argument specifies the number of milliseconds that should elapse between successive calls to `showTime(int)`.  Are you sure you don't want something more like `timer->start(1000);` ?

Comment: Do not delete the MRE since the idea is to understand what the OP problem was, obviously your code is incorrect if you had not asked the question. Read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two timers to a achieve this. The first timer is started to track the elapsed time. The second is used to track the remaining time.

```
countdown = QTime(0, 1, 30); // one minute and thirty seconds
timer.start()
```

Then in you timer callback the elapsed time can be subtracted from `countdown` to get the remaining time.

```
int elapsed_ms = timer.elapsed();
countdown.addMSecs( - elapsed_ms);
```

Comment: Thank you.the problem was solved by using doble timer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas,the problems was solved.the point is to use double timer.one is a qtimer,and the other is a qelapsed timer.
the qtime component is used to send signals constantly to the slot function,and in the slot funtion,int elapsed_ms = timer.elapsed();
countdown.addMSecs( - elapsed_ms)can realize a countdown timer. 
codes are below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTime>

#include <QDate>

#include <QTimer>

#include <QDebug>
#include<QElapsedTimer >

QElapsedTimer etimer;
QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
auto countdown=QTime(0,1,30);

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    etimer.start();

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showTime()));
    timer->start(10);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::showTime(){
    auto elapsed =etimer.elapsed();
    auto c=countdown.addMSecs(-elapsed);
    QString timestr = c.toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz"); //设置时间格式
    ui->lcdNumber->display(timestr);
}
```